Is there a way to partition/group by data where sum of column values per each group is under a limit?
i want to partition/group rows for every group of size <= limit
for example, if i have:
+--------+----------+
|      id|      size|
+--------+----------+
|       1|         3|
|       2|         6|
|       3|         8|
|       4|         5|
|       5|         7|
|       6|         7|
+--------+----------+

and i want to group rows by every size <=10, result would be:
+--------+----------+----------+
|      id|      size|     group|
+--------+----------+----------+
|       1|         3|         0|
|       2|         6|         0|
|       3|         8|         1|
|       4|         5|         2|
|       5|         7|         3|
|       6|         7|         4|
+--------+----------+----------+

another example, by every size <=13,
+--------+----------+----------+
|      id|      size|     group|
+--------+----------+----------+
|       1|         3|         0|
|       2|         6|         0|
|       3|         8|         1|
|       4|         5|         1|
|       5|         7|         2|
|       6|         7|         3|
+--------+----------+----------+

not even quite sure where to start with, have looked into window function, reduce function, user define aggregate function or adding addition columns (e.g. accumulate sum etc)..
the original task was to group request payload so that under a size limit they can be grouped into a single request.

I think you need not have perfect solution. Calculate average size value of size column. Find num_rows = limit / avg_size. Then create groups of num_rows and provide a random id to it. Over the groups, you can create groups using pandas grouped udf.

Here's an example. Since exact correctness is not required for you application, which implies we can have approximate correctness.
First we group the rows into suitable sizes. On those groups, we use pandas_udf grouped map to find subgroups which give you the optimum number of rows with < payload_limit.
Here's a possible example.
import math
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, floor, rand, pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sum, row_number, monotonically_increasing_id, count
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Example") \
    .getOrCreate()

data = [
    (1, 3),
    (2, 6),
    (3, 8),
    (4, 5),
    (5, 7),
    (6, 7),
    (11, 3),
    (12, 6),
    (13, 8),
    (14, 5),
    (15, 7),
    (16, 7),
    (21, 3),
    (22, 6),
    (23, 8),
    (24, 5),
    (25, 7),
    (26, 7)

]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "size"])

# Find the average size
avg_size = df.select(avg("size")).collect()[0][0]

payload_limit = 20
rows_per_group = math.floor(payload_limit / avg_size)
print(f"{avg_size=}")
print(f"{rows_per_group=}")
print(f"{df.count()=}")
nums_of_group = math.ceil(df.count() / rows_per_group)
print(f"{nums_of_group=}")

df = df.withColumn("random_group_id", floor(rand() * nums_of_group))
distinct_group_ids = df.select(col("random_group_id")).distinct()
distinct_group_ids.show(n=100, truncate=False)
print(f"{distinct_group_ids.count()}")

grouped_counts = df.groupby(col("random_group_id")).agg(count("*"))
grouped_counts.show(n=100, truncate=False)

df.show(n=100, truncate=False)

result_schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType()),
    StructField("size", IntegerType()),
    StructField("random_group_id", IntegerType()),
    StructField("sub_group", IntegerType()),
])


@pandas_udf(result_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def group_by_limit(pdf):
    limit = payload_limit
    group_col = "sub_group"

    print("before")
    print(pdf)

    # Calculate the cumulative sum of sizes within each random group
    pdf["cum_size"] = pdf.groupby("random_group_id")["size"].cumsum()

    # Assign group numbers based on the cumulative sum and limit
    pdf[group_col] = (pdf["cum_size"]) // limit


    # Drop the cumulative sum column
    pdf = pdf.drop("cum_size", axis=1)

    print("after")
    print(pdf)

    return pdf


# Apply the pandas UDF to the DataFrame
grouped_df = df.groupby("random_group_id").apply(group_by_limit)


grouped_df.show()

## Verify correctness of our algorithm.
result_grouped = grouped_df.groupBy("random_group_id", "sub_group").agg(sum("size"))
result_grouped.orderBy("random_group_id", "sub_group").show(n=100, truncate=False)

Output :
avg_size=6.0
rows_per_group=3
df.count()=18
nums_of_group=6
+---------------+
|random_group_id|
+---------------+
|5              |
|3              |
|1              |
|2              |
|4              |
+---------------+

5
+---------------+--------+
|random_group_id|count(1)|
+---------------+--------+
|5              |3       |
|3              |4       |
|1              |5       |
|2              |2       |
|4              |4       |
+---------------+--------+

+---+----+---------------+
|id |size|random_group_id|
+---+----+---------------+
|1  |3   |5              |
|2  |6   |3              |
|3  |8   |1              |
|4  |5   |5              |
|5  |7   |1              |
|6  |7   |1              |
|11 |3   |3              |
|12 |6   |3              |
|13 |8   |5              |
|14 |5   |2              |
|15 |7   |4              |
|16 |7   |1              |
|21 |3   |4              |
|22 |6   |2              |
|23 |8   |3              |
|24 |5   |1              |
|25 |7   |4              |
|26 |7   |4              |
+---+----+---------------+

+---+----+---------------+---------+
| id|size|random_group_id|sub_group|
+---+----+---------------+---------+
|  3|   8|              1|        0|
|  5|   7|              1|        0|
|  6|   7|              1|        1|
| 16|   7|              1|        1|
| 24|   5|              1|        1|
| 14|   5|              2|        0|
| 22|   6|              2|        0|
|  2|   6|              3|        0|
| 11|   3|              3|        0|
| 12|   6|              3|        0|
| 23|   8|              3|        1|
| 15|   7|              4|        0|
| 21|   3|              4|        0|
| 25|   7|              4|        0|
| 26|   7|              4|        1|
|  1|   3|              5|        0|
|  4|   5|              5|        0|
| 13|   8|              5|        0|
+---+----+---------------+---------+

+---------------+---------+---------+
|random_group_id|sub_group|sum(size)|
+---------------+---------+---------+
|1              |0        |15       |
|1              |1        |19       |
|2              |0        |11       |
|3              |0        |15       |
|3              |1        |8        |
|4              |0        |17       |
|4              |1        |7        |
|5              |0        |16       |
+---------------+---------+---------+


i choose to go with a function to take Iterator[Row], keep state variable inside and write the partition logic inside, but yours is a viable approach, thank you

choose whichever is faster on your dataset.
